# Force Azure to recycle the application pool instead of just the AppDomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm running software that interacts with unmanaged libraries. These libraries can't be used from a different AppDomain than they were loaded.

Thus, a new deployment causes failure.

Is there any way, on Azure websites, to request a reload of the application pool, or to prevent a new deployment from occuring in-process?

Comment: If you restart the website after deployment, does that not recycle the app pool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restarting the website after deployment will solve this issue. This can be done from the portal ("restart") or by using the PowerShell CmdLets or Node-CLI commands.

More info on those:

- http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/ (search for Restart-AzureWebsite)
- http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/ (azure site restart )

Comment: Thanks, I managed to miss the button - guess I was searching in the wrong place.

Comment: Link-only answer and the links provided don't provide the commands as promised

Comment: this doesnt help